# Place key-value pairs of a JSON object into separate columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a JSON object which I have declared in SQL Server like so

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json=N'{"success": "True",
 "timestamp": "1618498386",
 "base": "EUR",
 "date": "2021-04-15",
 "rates": {"AED": "4.395136",
  "AFN": "92.798516",
  "ALL": "123.01053",
  "AMD": "623.68381",
  "UAH": "33.449108",
  "UGX": "4330.311325",
  "USD": "1.196623"}}';

SELECT * FROM  
 OPENJSON ( @json )  
WITH (   
              AED   varchar(200) '$.rates.AED',
              USD   varchar(200) '$.rates.USD',  
              Date     datetime     '$.date',  
              BASE_CURR varchar(200) '$.base'
 )
```

From the above JSON object I am trying to build a structured table as follows

| base | date | CURR_KEY | CURR_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EUR | 2021-04-15 | AED | 4.395136 |
| EUR | 2021-04-15 | AFN | 92.798516 |
| EUR | 2021-04-15 | ALL | 123.01053 |
| EUR | 2021-04-15 | AMD | 623.68381 |
| EUR | 2021-04-15 | UAH | 33.449108 |
| EUR | 2021-04-15 | UGX | 4330.311325 |
| EUR | 2021-04-15 | USD | 1.196623 |

I referred the relevant [Option 2 in Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) which shows how to place keys of a JSON object as column names and values as row values (**UPDATE: refer the query above**). As you can see from the above table, my requirements are to place both keys and values in two separate columns.

Comment: Have you had a look at `OPENJSON`? What did you try with it if you did? What about said attempt(s) didn't work?

Comment: You do not have a JSON object.  You have an NVARCHAR() which seems to have contents that resemble a JSON object.

Comment: @Larnu, updated the question with the tried query.

Comment: @Luuk, That's right. I have assigned a JSON object to NVARCHAR().

Comment: select r.*, json_value(@json, '$.date'/*$.base*/) from openjson(@json, '$.rates') as r

Comment: .. @SoakingHummer  

Comment: @lptr if you could post your comment as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: .. @SoakingHummer, feel free to accept the answer of charlieface.. it is a more complete than my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could use `OPENJSON` or `JSON_VALUE` to get the root object.**

Then you need `OPENJSON` without a schema to get key/value pairs of `'$.rates'`.

```sql
SELECT
    j.base,
    j.date,
    CAST(rates.[key] AS char(3)) as CURR_KEY,
    CAST(rates.value AS decimal(15,6)) as CURR_VALUE
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH ([base] char(3),
           [date] date,
           rates nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) j
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j.Rates) rates;
```

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.base') AS base,
    JSON_VALUE(@json, '$.date') AS date,
    cast(rates.[key] as char(3)) as CURR_KEY,
    cast(rates.value as decimal(15,6)) as CURR_VALUE
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.rates') rates;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is using 2 calls to `OPENJSON`:

```sql
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @json=N'{"success": "True",
 "timestamp": "1618498386",
 "base": "EUR",
 "date": "2021-04-15",
 "rates": {"AED": "4.395136",
  "AFN": "92.798516",
  "ALL": "123.01053",
  "AMD": "623.68381",
  "UAH": "33.449108",
  "UGX": "4330.311325",
  "USD": "1.196623"}}';

 
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
     WITH (BASE_CURR varchar(200) '$.base',
           [Date] date,
           rates nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON) OJ
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(OJ.Rates)
                 WITH (AED decimal(15,6),
                       USD decimal(15,6)) R;
```